# call (consume) web service in oracle 12c pl/sql

Tags: web-services, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to call/consume a web service that returns a static string.  The below code throws an error (scroll below) on execution.  Appreciate help.

Oracle Version: 12.2.0.1

Oracle wallet is setup
Execute privileges exists for UTL_HTTP, UTL_SMTP, UTL_TCP

Scrambled the URL, the actual URL does return the static string

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WS_TST
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_req           UTL_HTTP.req;
    v_resp          UTL_HTTP.resp;

    v_msg           VARCHAR2 (32767);
    v_entire_msg    VARCHAR2 (32767) := NULL;

    v_RR            NUMBER;

    v_wallet_path   VARCHAR2 (32767);

    --v_url                VARCHAR2(32767) :=  'https://dcaopppm.com/RecalcSer/api/AT/RR?stat=3&Do=01/01/2015&SType=P&Dob=01/01/1990';
    
BEGIN
    v_wallet_path := 'file:/u01/app/oracle/admin/DEVDBINST/wallet';

    UTL_HTTP.set_wallet (v_wallet_path, NULL);

    v_req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request (url => v_url, method => 'GET');

    v_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response (r => v_req);

    BEGIN
        LOOP
            UTL_HTTP.read_text (r => v_resp, data => v_msg);
            v_entire_msg := v_entire_msg || v_msg;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('v_entire_msg: ' || v_entire_msg);
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body
        THEN
            NULL;
    END;

    v_entire_msg := REPLACE (v_entire_msg, CHR (13));
    v_entire_msg := REPLACE (v_entire_msg, CHR (10));
    v_entire_msg :=
        REPLACE (v_entire_msg, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>');
    v_entire_msg :=
        REPLACE (v_entire_msg,
                 '<double xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/">');    
    v_entire_msg := REPLACE (v_entire_msg, '</double>');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('v_entire_msg: ' || v_entire_msg);


    BEGIN
        v_RR := TO_CHAR (v_entire_msg);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS
        THEN
            v_RR := NULL;
    END;

    UTL_HTTP.end_response (r => v_resp);

    RETURN v_RR;
END WS_TST;
```

Error upon execution:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-28759: failure to open file
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1127
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue is in these two lines:

```
 v_wallet_path := 'file:/u01/app/oracle/admin/DEVDBINST/wallet';
 UTL_HTTP.set_wallet (v_wallet_path, NULL);
```

Please ensure that your wallet is in fact in this repository. Keep in mind that this should point to the folder where the wallet is located and not the wallet file itself. Also make sure that the wallet file is named `ewallet.p12`.

If all is in place, please ensure that you do not in fact have a password on the wallet.

Lastly what comes to my mind is that your DB is unable to read this folder. Try to also grant read permissions on this folder.

This is what worked in the past for me. Please do come back with feedback whether it worked! Best of luck!